# Angular 2 HTTP Request: TypeError: backend.createConnection is not a function

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I'm trying to run a simple HTTP request in Angular and am running into the following error:

> angular2.dev.js:23941 Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of AlbumListComponent!.
>   ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: backend.createConnection is not a function

To simplify I broke down the HTTP functionality to its simplest removing the service and just directly accessing the HTTP service and Observable:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Album} from './album';
import {AppState} from './appstate'; 
import {Observable}     from 'rxjs/Observable';

import {Http}    from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'album-list',
    templateUrl: 'Views/albumList.html',
    providers: [AlbumService, Http, Response]        
})
export class AlbumListComponent {
    albums: Array<Album> = [];
    title: string = "Album Listing";
    errorMessage: string;


    constructor(public state: AppState,
        public albumService: AlbumService,
        public http: Http) {

        console.log('AlbumList Constructor' +  this.title);
        state.activeTab = "albums";
        debugger;

        http.get(state.urls.albums)
            .map(res => {
                debugger;
                return res.json()
            })
            //.catch(error => {
            //    debugger;
            //    console.error(error);
            //    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
            //})
            .subscribe(albums => this.albums = albums)           

        //this.getAlbums();  // service removed to simplify
    }


}
```

Bootstrap code (and http.dev.js is included in the script list):

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Albumviewer} from './albumviewer.component';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {AppState} from './appstate'
import 'rxjs/Rx';

bootstrap(Albumviewer,[
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
]);
```

I either get the described error, or errors about missing providers (like ConnectionBackend).

If I remove the Http access code the app runs OK. With the code in there it bombs. I have no idea what to look at here - as the error message clearly refers to a child component used by the HTTP service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**update**

In Angular2 final adding `HttpModule` to imports of `@NgModule()` does the same

**original**

You don't show your `bootstrap(...)` but it probably doesn't contain `HTTP_PROVIDERS`

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

`HTTP_PROVIDERS` contains `Http` and all its dependencies. If you add `HTTP_PROVIDERS` to `bootstrap()` there is no need to add `Http` to providers on components because this way it is made globally available.

You still need to import it if you want to inject it though.

Comment: I did have HTTP_PROVIDERS registered in the bootstrap code, so that wasn't quite the issue. But you did point me in the right direction. The issue turned out to be adding the Http provider explicitly - if I remove the Http provider reference then the code above starts working.

Comment: I can confirm that removing Http from the providers fixes this problem, which only occured in a spec test which calls a "real" fake backend :)      
(ng 2.0.0)

Answer (score 2):

**HTTP_PROVIDERS** is deprecated from 2.0.

You can use something like this instead:

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

and in your decorator:

```
imports:[ BrowserModule, HttpModule ]
```

**Note:** Make sure to remove **Http** from providers

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue in RC5, to resolve in my case:

In Component (Where `{ServiceName}` is the name of the HTTP Service):

```
// import HTTP_PROVIDERS at the top:
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';

// in the @Component decorator
providers: [ {ServiceName}, HTTP_PROVIDERS ]
```

In app.module.ts:

```
// import ConnectionBackend and HTTP_PROVIDERS
import { ConnectionBackend, HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';

// in the @NgModule decorator
providers: [
    ConnectionBackend,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    ...
]
```

Hope this helps anyone getting this issue in RC5